# How to list printers drivers without credential with Samba?

Tags: samba

In order to automatise check of printers, I would like to call rpc commands such as  `enumprinter` or `enumdriver`.

How to make it without connecting to the SMB domain but directly as root?

With `rpcclient` Domain credential must be provided.  With `smbclient` I can only get the list of shared printers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the setup of the machines in question, you may be able to use `rpcclient` as the anonymous user:

```
rpcclient -U "" -N -c enumprinters YOURMACHINE
```

Note that this may not work for Windows machines with the default group policy, but should work for most Samba setups.

Comment: Works on all my machine except one (which is identical to the others) : I got `Could not initialise lsa pipe.  Error was NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED Could not obtain sid for MY_DOMAIN` etc etc  Do you know what to do to in this case?

Comment: Not yet. That's the same problem you get when trying to connect to Windows machines as the anonymous user, so if you can work out how to solve it you might have come up with a more general solution.